# can not find 'form' attribute this.props.form react

Tags: reactjs

I'm absoloutly beginner in react and I copied the code for a Login-Form from the antdesign website. but now i get this error message. can you please help me to find the error?

> "'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>' can not find 'form'
>   attribute. "

This is the code:

```
class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component <{}, { value: string }>{
handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.form.validateFields((err: any, values: any) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    } 
  });
}
render() {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
      <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
        })(
          <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
        )}
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('password', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
        })(
          <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        )}
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
          valuePropName: 'checked',
          initialValue: true,
        })}

      </FormItem>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create()(NormalLoginForm);

Answer (score -2):

First of all you have to understand the props concept before using. 
Secondly i see the error what ever you are getting 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>' can not find 'form' attribute. " and the code you have pasted for reference is not in sync.

As i see the code, the component is using a prop called 'form' which should be either 
passed by the parent component of this 'NormalLoginForm', or the props should be available in its own reference (mapSateToProps).

Based on minimal code reference provided: 
I see there can be two problem in this case. 
1. 'form' props is not passed to the particular component. 
2. form is overriding : if you are passing a "form" prop from parent (with reference of different data) and also giving a internal reference of 'form' prop (mapStateToProps) in this case you may find such problems.

Solution:

1. Where ever you are rendering "NormalLoginForm",  pass 'form' props from there
     < NormalLoginForm form={{"give your form object what you want to pass"} />

   ```
                                         OR
   ```
2. If you have wrapped "NormalLoginForm" with some parent component then don't need to pass the props, it will be automatically available (if the prop is expected from parent).

Note: If a component is a child of something always try to pass the required props from parent and try to make the child stateless.